# Conditionally run tests with or without mocks with jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I'm running tests with mocks so that the tests don't always hit APIs. I however also want to add a condition, so that I can use the same test to tests the APIs.

When I however add a condition, it ignores it and never applies the mocks no matter if the condition is true or false.

```js
import config from 'config';
if(!config.test.useNetwork) {
    jest.mock('api/companies');
    jest.mock('api/articles');
}

import { searchCompany } from 'api/companies';
...
```

Two questions:

1. Any idea for how to add conditional mocks? I think mocks never apply because `jest.mock` might need to be called before any imports?
2. What's the convention for testing over the network? If I just use mocks, I'm really just testing the mocks, and not the network request code. But if I don't use mocks I'm unnecessarily hitting the API.

Answer (score 2):

One:

Yes, `jest.mock()` is ["hoisted to the top of the code block"](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/jest-object.html#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options).  However, `jest.doMock` is not hoisted.  So, you can accomplish what you want thus:

```
const config = require('./config').default;
if(!config.test.useNetwork) {
    jest.doMock('api/companies');
    jest.doMock('api/articles');
}

const { searchCompany } = require('api/companies');
```

Two:

That's a controversial question. It isn't suited for StackOverflow and I'm not touching it lol

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar question [that I have answered for myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58105119/1183252) and a found another solution.

You can use the second parameter (factory) to decide whether you want to return a mock or the actual module

```
import config from 'config';
import { searchCompany } from 'api/companies';

jest.mock('api/companies', () => {
  if(!config.test.useNetwork) return jest.genMockFromModule('api/companies');
  return jest.requireActual('api/companies');
});
```

Comment: This didn't work for some reason for me

Comment: By now I learned that you need to implement this differently whether or not the required modules is loaded as an ES module (import xxx) or via CSJ (require(xxx)) but I am usually stimm just running through a phase of trial and error until "something" works