# Jest: Use module mock only on the CI and locally use the original implementation

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I am [writing a Bluetooth library](https://github.com/LukasBombach/sblendid/) and I am testing it with Jest. For my tests I am doing actual radio communication to make sure everything actually works. These kind of tests however cannot be run on a CI system. So for my CI system, and my CI system only, I want to use a mock. For local development, I don't want to mock anything.

So I tried to conditionally mock a module in jest:

```
import MyModule from "./myModule";

if (true) {
  jest.mock("./myModule");
}

describe("MyModule", () => {
  let myModule;

  beforeEach(() => {
    myModule = new MyModule();
  });

  test("I am NOT mocked", () => {
    expect(myModule.powerOn()).toBe("I am the original implementation");
  });

  test("I am mocked", () => {
    if (myModule.powerOn.mockReturnValueOnce)
      myModule.powerOn.mockReturnValueOnce("I am a mock");
    expect(myModule.powerOn()).toBe("I am a mock");
  });
});
```

but that does not work. My test results are

> ```
>  FAIL  ./index.test.js
>   MyModule
>     ✓ I am NOT mocked (3ms)
>     ✕ I am mocked (6ms)
>
>   ● MyModule › I am mocked
>
>     expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality
>
>     Expected: "I am a mock"
>     Received: "I am the original implementation"
>
>       19 |     if (myModule.powerOn.mockReturnValueOnce)
>       20 |       myModule.powerOn.mockReturnValueOnce("I am a mock");
>     > 21 |     expect(myModule.powerOn()).toBe("I am a mock");
>          |                                ^
>       22 |   });
>       23 | });
>       24 | 
>
>       at Object.toBe (index.test.js:21:32)
>
> Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
> Tests:       1 failed, 1 passed, 2 total
> Snapshots:   0 total
> ```

Once I remove the if clause

```
if (true) {
  jest.mock("./myModule");
}
```

to

```
jest.mock("./myModule");
```

it works as expected.

You can try it out here

https://github.com/LukasBombach/jest-conditionally-mock-module-example

I can't put it in a CodeSanbox, because this code breaks it.

I have read that jest needs to have module mocks in the root scope of your file because it parses your file before it runs it and does some magic on it. *I know this*.

But since it seems that it is not possible to put `jest.mock` in an if clause, is there any other way I can make my CI use a mock and locally work with my actual implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the solution myself. There is [a related question to this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570329/conditionally-run-tests-with-or-without-mocks-with-jest) but I found another solution that I like better. You can use the second parameter (factory) to decide whether you want to return a mock or the actual module

See for yourself

```
import MyModule from "./myModule";

jest.mock("./myModule", () => {
  if (false) return jest.requireActual("./myModule");
  return jest.genMockFromModule("./myModule");
});

describe("MyModule", () => {
  const myModule = new MyModule();

  test("I am the original", () => {
    expect(myModule.powerOn()).toBe("I am the original implementation");
  });

  test("I am mocked", () => {
    myModule.powerOn.mockReturnValueOnce("I am a mock");
    expect(myModule.powerOn()).toBe("I am a mock");
  });
});
```